# programmatically determining Cassandra columns at runtime

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm accessing a Cassandra database and I only know the table names.

I want to discover the names & types of the columns.

This will give me the column names:

```
select column_name 
  from system.schema_columns 
where columnfamily_name = 'customer' 
allow filtering;
```

Is this reasonable?

Does anyone have suggestions about determining column types?

Comment: You can try "describe" statement:  Describe Table [keyspace].customer

Comment: `describe` only works from within cqlsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can infer the column types by looking at the classes used for the validator.  The validator column is just a string.

The string has one of 3 formats:

org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.XXXType for simple column types, where XXX is the Java type for the column (e.g. for bigint columns, XXX is "Long", for varchar/text, XXX is "UTF8", etc.)

org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SetType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.XXXType) for set columns, where the type in parenthesis is the type of each set element

org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MapType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.XXXType,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.XXXType) for maps

Comment: i'm a cassandra newbie.  can you describe a bit more about how i would accomplish looking at classes used for the validator?

Comment: Sorry, the validator is listed in the last column for table system.schema_columns, This is just a string column, where the value is the name of the class that does the validations.  You would have to parse these strings.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what driver you're using, you should be able to use the metadata API.

A couple examples:

http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/metadata.html#schemas
https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/features/metadata/#schema-metadata

The drivers query the system schema metadata to create these models.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old but still valid question. There is a class variable of your model that describe columns (field name and column class):

```
class Tweet(cqldb.Model):
    """
    Object representing the tweet column family in Cassandra
    """
    __keyspace__ = 'my_ks'
    # follows model definition
    ...
    ...

print(Tweet._defined_columns)

# output

OrderedDict([('tweetid',
                        <cassandra.cqlengine.columns.Text at 0x7f4a4c9b66a0>),
                       ('tweet_id',
                        <cassandra.cqlengine.columns.BigInt at 0x7f4a4c9b6828>),
                       ('created_at',
                        <cassandra.cqlengine.columns.DateTime at 0x7f4a4c9b6748>),
                       ('ttype',
                        <cassandra.cqlengine.columns.Text at 0x7f4a4c9b6198>),
                       ('tweet',
                        <cassandra.cqlengine.columns.Text at 0x7f4a4c9b6390>),
                       ('lang',
                        <cassandra.cqlengine.columns.Text at 0x7f4a4c9b3d68>)])
```